# Entity framework 6 no results

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

Ive just setup entity framework 6 (for first time) using a model with same fields as db table but im getting 0 results on debug (no errors)

```
public class footballContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<football> football { get; set; }

}
```

and:

```
var context = new footballContext();
var matches = context.football.Take(20).ToList();
```

If I view the query its using on "context" I can run it on my database and results are returned fine. I do have entity framework power tools but it only seems to validate the model, is there a way I can test if it can get data or is there something obvious I've missed?

Comment: Double check your connection string.  Are you connecting to a local db or a remote one?  My first hunch is that your are running your query against an existing remote db but your code is running against a local one which has no seed data.

Answer (score 0):

Just found this:

> "If you don't specify a connection string or the name of one explicitly, Entity Framework assumes that the connection string name is the same as the class name. The default connection string name in this example would then be SchoolContext, the same as what you're specifying explicitly."

Think I need to start reading up on the naming conventions for this...

Answer (score 0):

For your code to work as it stands, you will need to have a connection string in your web.config called footballContext

If you don't want the connection string to be called that you can create a constructor for your context which calls the base constructor with a specified name.

If you prefer to pass in the connection string explicitly during creation of the context you can again create a constructor for footballContext which accepts a connection string and calls the appropriate base constructor.

See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24241050) for an example.