# Entity Framework cannot connect to local SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, database-connection, connection-string

I'm using EF6 code first to connect to local instance of SQL Server,
and although I already set the connection string to local instance
it keep getting to the SQL Express instead of the full version instance.

In SQL Server Explorer it shows two : localdb/mssqlocaldb and myPC.

My connection string :

```
<add name="MyDatabase" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=MyPC\MSSQLSERVER;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

Anyone could help to point out what am I doing wrong or missing here ?

Thank you

Comment: instead of mypc try to replace it with (localdb) if it's connected with vs

Comment: And you are using the connection string properly in the code?

Comment: Have you added it to the context constructor. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24240761/passing-connection-string-to-entity-framework-6)

Comment: @Gino There are two instance showing up in my VS, the (localdb)MSSQLlocalDB and myPC

Comment: @Steve Greene Yes, I did. and funny enough that it still doesnt point to the specified db