# Writing and Retrieving connection string for Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Initially, I was building and saving the connection string in the app.config file for the project upon logon.  However, one of our in house users was having incidents where the data saved to the DB was inexplicably not there. Though logging off and back on again alleviated the issue.

I have since realized that since we all use a shared copy of the program stored on our share drive with shortcuts on our desktops, every time someone logs in, it changes the connection string, which is also shared by all.

So, I have been trying to save it to a local user file under the %appData% folder.

This is what I had before, which would work if we used local copies of the application.

```
public class UpdateConfig
{
    public static void UpdateConfigConnString(string s)
    { 

        var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        var connectionStringsSection = (ConnectionStringsSection)config.GetSection("connectionStrings");
        connectionStringsSection.ConnectionStrings["MyDB"].ConnectionString = s;
        config.Save();
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
    }

}
```

I attempted to just change the `ConfigurationUserLevel` to `None`, but that gave me an error about not being able to change a locked item.

This is where I am now, based on this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms134265(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation:

```
public class UpdateConfig
{
    public static void UpdateConfigConnString(string s)
    {
        string sectionName = "MyDB";

        var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoaming);
        ExeConfigurationFileMap configFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
        configFileMap.ExeConfigFilename = config.FilePath;
        var currentSection = (ConnectionStringsSection)config.GetSection(sectionName);
        if (currentSection == null)
        {
            currentSection = new ConnectionStringsSection();

            currentSection.SectionInformation.AllowExeDefinition = ConfigurationAllowExeDefinition.MachineToRoamingUser;
            currentSection.SectionInformation.AllowOverride = true;
            currentSection.ConnectionStrings.Add(new ConnectionStringSettings("MyDB", s));

        }

        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
        Debug.WriteLine(config.FilePath);

        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
    }

}
```

Running this doesn't really tell me much, other than it doesn't error out. However, when I try to find the file that the `Debug.WriteLine` prints out, Windows can't find it. Additionally, I am not real sure how to make sure that my Entity Framework Project know where to look for the connection string.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Or if I am going about this all wrong, I am open to suggestions on a better way, thanks.

Comment: At which point is the code being run? Is this run as part of your start up code (in Program.cs)? Are you running it before your startup form is loaded?

Comment: After the user makes a selection in the main form.

Answer (score 0):

If you are required to dynamically change the connection string depending on user input, none of the above approaches would work. You cannot save a config file in each users app data since you run the exe file from a shared location. On a different note, updating the exe file in this case is a very bad practice itself. Therefore is it best not to update the config file and think of an alternative approach.

In my opinion what you should do is to build the path to pass a custom connection string to Entity Framework. You can easily create a constructor overload that would accept a custom connection string and pass it along. Since you already have the custom connection string in hand, it is matter of adding the plumbing code to pass it. See the below post of how to do it:

[Passing connection string to EF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24240761/passing-connection-string-to-entity-framework-6)

Hope this helps!

Comment: So, set a global variable, and pass that each time I want to use a DBContext? To be honest, I was trying to avoid that, but after a day and a half of nothing working and your input, I guess that is the best route.

Comment: Using a global variable or not depends on how you have designed you data layer. Global variable is an easy way out which I would use as the last resort... If you are using a repository/ repository like pattern, it would make sense to pass it from along and keep in within the repository 'manager' boundary - assuming you would not create multiple manager instances every time a CRUD request is being made; in other words you are looking for a singleton instance of a repository manager which holds the connection string and pass whenever/ who ever the repositories that require creating a DBContext.